# Python writing apostrophes to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm converting a downloaded Facebook Messenger conversation from JSON to a text file using Python. I've converted the JSON to text and it's all looking fine. I need to strip the unnecessary information and reverse the order of the messages, then save the output to a file, which I've done. However, when I am formatting the messages with Python, when I look at the output file, sometimes instead of an apostrophe, there's â instead.

My Python isn't great as I normally work with Java, so there's probably a lot of things I could improve. If someone could suggest some better tags for this question, I'd also be very appreciative.

Example of apostrophe working: You're not making them are you?

Example of apostrophe not working: Itâs just a button I discovered

What is causing this to happen and why does not happen every time there is an apostrophe?

Here is the script:

```
#/usr/bin/python3

import datetime

def main():

    input_file = open('messages.txt', 'r')
    output_file = open('results.txt', 'w')

    content_list = []
    sender_name_list = []
    time_list = []

    line = input_file.readline()

    while line:
        line = input_file.readline()

        if "sender_name" in line:
            values = line.split("sender_name")
            sender_name_list.append(values[1][1:])

        if "timestamp_ms" in line:
            values = line.split("timestamp_ms")
            time_value = values[1]
            timestamp = int(time_value[1:])         
            time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp / 1000.0)      
            time_truncated = time.replace(microsecond=0)
            time_list.append(time_truncated)    

        if "content" in line:
            values = line.split("content")
            content_list.append(values[1][1:])

    content_list.reverse()
    sender_name_list.reverse()
    time_list.reverse()

    for x in range(1, len(content_list)):
        output_file.write(sender_name_list[x])
        output_file.write(str(time_list[x]))
        output_file.write("\n")
        output_file.write(content_list[x])
        output_file.write("\n\n")


input_file.close()
output_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit:
The answer to the question was adding

```
import codecs
input_file = codecs.open('messages.txt', 'r', 'utf-8')
output_file = codecs.open('results.txt','w', 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Please add the input, output and desired output to your question. Your textual description is not very clear.

Comment: Where are you seeing ```â```? In the text file converted from JSON? Or is there another output file after that?

Comment: If you feel the answer below addressed your question, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the incoming data it's hard to be sure, but I suspect that instead of an apostrophe (`Unicode U+0027 ' APOSTROPHE`), you've got a curly-equivalent (`U+2019 ’ RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`) in there trying to be interpreted as old-fashioned ascii.

Instead of

```
output_file = open('results.txt', 'w')
```

try

```
import codecs
output_file = codecs.open('results.txt','w', 'utf-8')
```

You may also need the equivalent on your input file.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and I get UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 141: ordinal not in range(128). What does this mean?. Edit: I added the same line to the input_file and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Glad it worked. Although I have to admit, I am slightly thrown by the  0xc3. I would have expected 0xe2, which is the first byte of utf-8-encoded U+2019 ’ RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (see https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm); and 0xe2 is also the "extended ascii" for that 'â' character you're seeing (see https://www.ascii-code.com). So how a 0xc3 got in there, I have no clue.

Anyway, glad it helped.

Comment: FWIW you don't need to use `codecs.open` in Python3, you can specify an encoding in the `open` builtin:  `open('results.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')`.  If left unspecified `open` will use the platform default.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, good point, that's clearly the superior approach. I happened to have some code handy that used `codecs`, so I went with that since I could be sure it would be likely to work.